# Filter items from nested json

Tags: javascript, json

There is a json:

```
x = [
{"name":"Peter", "list":[{"position":"high", "id":"ZZ"},
                         {"position":"low", "id":"KJ"}]},
{"name":"Alise", "list":[{"position":"high", "id":"TC"},
                         {"position":"low", "id":"ZZ"}]}
]
```

I need to get rid of those items in "list", which contain "id":"ZZ" using filter().
I expect the following result in the end:

```
[
{"name":"Peter", "list":[{"position":"low", "id":"KJ"}]},
{"name":"Alise", "list":[{"position":"low", "id":"ZZ"}]}
]
```

My attempt to achieve this:

```
y = for (i=0;i<x.length;++i){
        for (n=0;n<x[i]["list"].length;++n){
             x[i]["list"][n].filter(id => "id" == "ZZ")
        }
    }
```

The browser console output says

```
Uncaught TypeError: x[i]["list"][n].filter is not a function.
```

Could you tell me how can I filter the given json and get rid of "id":"ZZ" lines?

Comment: life saving question, thanks Ramzes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a `map` for the each element and `filter` for each `list` of that element

I use spread operator here to keep other property the same and just modify the `list`

```js
const x = [
  {
    name: "Peter",
    list: [
      { position: "high", id: "ZZ" },
      { position: "low", id: "KJ" },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Alise",
    list: [
      { position: "high", id: "TC" },
      { position: "low", id: "ZZ" },
    ],
  },
];

const res = x.map((el) => ({
  ...el,
  list: el.list.filter(({ id }) => id !== "ZZ"),
}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You saved me bro. your solution had a great impact for my problem to be fixed, i was struggling the whole days but none of the solutions helped me out without yours. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [ { name: 'Peter', list: [{ position: 'high', id: 'ZZ' }, { position: 'low', id: 'KJ' }] }, { name: 'Alise', list: [{ position: 'high', id: 'TC' }, { position: 'low', id: 'ZZ' }] } ];

const prune = (data, id) => objectScan(['[*].list[*]'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value, property, parent }) => {
    if (value.id === id) {
      parent.splice(property, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data);

console.log(prune(myData, 'ZZ')); // returns the number of deletions
// => 2

console.log(myData);
// => [ { name: 'Peter', list: [ { position: 'low', id: 'KJ' } ] }, { name: 'Alise', list: [ { position: 'high', id: 'TC' } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)